# Multiple Instances of ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a single view that performs tasks via ICommand.  The view performs a task on a list of selected items from a listview.  I get the list of selected item's via the selection_changed event in the code behind.  The action on those items is performed via a command.   The list of selected items in the view model doesn't match between the two calls.  The list of selected items after items are selected is correct,  the list of selected items referenced by the command is empty.  I determined the list isn't being reinstantiated or cleared by checking the memory addresses of the lists.  The memory addresses are different.

**Why do I have two instances of SelectedPrices?**

View XAML

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:AdminViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AdminViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<ListView x:Name="lvCustomerPrices"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     Margin="14,82,0,32"
     Width="1362"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
     SelectionChanged="lvCustomerPrices_SelectionChanged">
...
```

View Code Behind

```
public partial class ExportAdminView : Window
{
    protected AdminViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (AdminViewModel)Resources["ViewModel"]; }
    }

    public ExportAdminView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void lvCustomerPrices_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SetSelectedPrices(lvCustomerPrices.SelectedItems.Cast<DailyCustomerPrice>());
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class AdminViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<DailyCustomerPrice> SelectedPrices { get; set; } = new List<DailyCustomerPrice>();

    public bool CanExportToEmail => (SelectedPrices.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExportEmailAddress));

    public ICommand ExportPricesToEmailCommand { get; set; }

    public AdminViewModel()
    {
        ExportPricesToEmailCommand = new RelayCommand(ExportPrices, () => CanExportToEmail);
        PriceEffectiveDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
    }

    public void SetSelectedPrices(IEnumerable<DailyCustomerPrice> selectedItems)
    {
        SelectedPrices.Clear();
        SelectedPrices.AddRange(selectedItems);
    }
}
```

RelayCommand (I need to clean this up and make a separate class for parameters)

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _executeWithParameter;
    private Action _execute;
    private Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
    {}

    public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
    {}

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        if (canExecute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));

        this._execute = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }


    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }

        if (canExecute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
        }

        this._executeWithParameter = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            this.CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            this.CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChangedInternal;
        //DispatcherHelper.BeginInvokeOnUIThread(() => handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty));
        handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        _canExecute = () => false;
        _executeWithParameter = _ => { return; };
        _execute = null;
    }

    private static bool DefaultCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The SelectedPrices in the AdminViewModel.CanExportToEmail property has a different memory address than the SelectedPrices in the SetSelectedPrices method.

I need these to be in sync.

Comment: When you add an item to one, is it not added to the other?

Comment: Yes.  Items added in the SelectionChanged event do not exist in the CanExportToEmail property, but the items added in the selectionChanged event persist in it's copy of the list when the event fires again.  Additionally,  I can add item's to the SelectedPrices collection in the CanExportToEmail property via the debugger and they too persist between calls.

Comment: I think there's a chance you have two instances of `AdminViewModel`; if so, then the value of `this` in those two places should differ as well.

Comment: "the list isn't being reinstantiated" -- I've heard that term used to mean a new instance being created and assigned to the same variable/field (hence the pointer would change); what do you mean by it?

Comment: You are correct.  I misused the term.  I believe there are two instances of the view model one being accessed by the selection changed event in the event handler and the other during the SelectedPrices check in the CanExportToEmail property invoked by the ICommand.

Comment: You know that you are creating 2 instances of `AdminViewModel` right? First time when you set it as DataContext in XAML, second time, when you get it in code behind. Get rid of one of them

Comment: @lokusking How did I miss that? Yes, that's it of course.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hehehe... Was a long day buddy ;)

Comment: @lokusking,  How do I reference the viewmodel instantiated in the xaml from the code behind?

Comment: Just get it with `(AdminViewModel)this.DataContext`

Comment: Great Thanks!  Want to move your solution an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your issue, either remove your `AdminViewModel` from XAML or from Code-Behind.

To get access to it in Code-Behind, grab your `AdminViewModel` with `(AdminViewModel)this.DataContext`.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:AdminViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AdminViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And try this;

```
public ExportAdminView()
{
   this.DataContext = new AdminViewModel();
   InitializeComponent();  
}
```