# Duplicate Model instantiated from InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a MVVM WPF application and have run into a dead end trying to solve this. %)
I have a model class **DeviceModel** instantiated from *App.xaml.cs*. This model implements *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public DeviceModel DeviceModelInstance { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        DeviceModelInstance = new DeviceModel();
    }
}
```

In *App.xaml*:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="ViewModelBaseApp"/>
    <m:DeviceModel x:Key="DeviceModelApp"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then from *MainWindow.xaml* I instantiate the **ViewModelBase**:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
         <Binding Source="{StaticResource ViewModelBaseApp}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Then I bind buttons in the UI (*MainWindow.xaml*) to commands in **ViewModelBase**, which implement *ICommand* interface:

```
    Command="{Binding InputPhantomCommand, Converter={StaticResource InputPhantomConverter}, Source={StaticResource ViewModelBaseApp}}"
```

This works great! I push a button, a command in the **ViewModelBase** gets called and changes a property of the **DeviceModelInstance** (instantiated in *App.xaml.cs*), which in turn triggers a *PropertyChanged* event, which propagates to other classes listening to that event. All the **ICommand bound buttons** in the UI work this way.
However, when I bind **sliders** to properties in the **DeviceModel** class, i.e.:

```
    Value="{Binding InputChannel2.Gain, Converter={StaticResource InputGainConverter}, Source={StaticResource DeviceModelApp}}"
```

All of the sliders get bound to a **duplicate DeviceModel** class, which gets instantiated at **InitializeComponent()** method in the constructor of *MainWindow.xaml.cs*. When I move any of the sliders, the duplicate model reacts fine to changes. All of the labels that are bound to the same properties as sliders get dynamically updated. Yet, all of the events are listened to on the **original DeviceModelInstance** object (from *App.xaml.cs*) and no events occur, obviously.

I cannot figure out why all of the buttons are interacting with the **DeviceModelInstance** that I created in *App.xaml.cs*, while all of the sliders and their corresponding labels are interacting with a **duplicate DeviceModel()** that gets created at InitializeComponent() of MainWindow...

I suspect it's an issue of referencing the original **DeviceModelInstance** correctly in XAML, but I don't know how to do this. Thank you! )

Comment: You are intentionally creating two DeviceModel instances, one in the App constructor, the other in Application.Resources.

Comment: But if I omit <m:DeviceModel x:Key="DeviceModelApp"/> from App.xaml, how do I use the previously created DeviceModelInstance as a StaticResource in MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Why are you creating a DeviceModel property in App.xaml?

Comment: You're making this very complex for some weird reason.  Get rid of your resources.  Have one root view model which has a public property with your DeviceModel in it.  Set the DataContext to your root view model in your codebehind.

Comment: @mm8 : I'm creating DeviceModel in App.xaml because then I can use it as a StaticResource within XAML elements. If I don't define it in XAML, I have no way of binding any of the elements to that model.

Comment: "If I don't define it in XAML, I have no way of binding any of the elements to that model." That's not true. Set the DataContext to a top-level view model with a ViewModelBase and a DeviceModel property.

Comment: @Will: The reason most likely is being an absolute beginner to C#/MVVM, coming from procedural C firmware-style habits... I will attempt what you're suggesting, but the reason I have relocated the DeviceModelInstance into App.xaml.cs from ViewModelBase.cs where it originally was is because the ViewModelBase was also being created multiple times from XAML.. I'm trying really hard to grasp these concepts. I need DeviceModelInstance to be a singleton and to be accessible both from XAML bindings and other classes easily.

Comment: Ok, so, I removed resources from XAML, added public property of DeviceModel inside of ViewModelBase and set DataContext = new ViewModelBase() in MainWindow.xaml.cs. But now VS says "DataContext is not set in markup", which is why in the past I've added DataContext through XAML, which would create a duplicate ViewModelBase that way and the problem would remain..

Comment: Been using wpf since it came out and I have never *ever* seen "datacontext is not set in markup".  That also returns zero hits. Something weird is going on with your application. Without the exact error I can't tell you what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in addition to clues given in comments by Will and Clemens, somehow this answer cleared it up for me even more - [Multiple Instances of ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666273/multiple-instances-of-viewmodel)

Specifically, the line:

> To get access to it in Code-Behind, grab your AdminViewModel with (AdminViewModel)this.DataContext.

In my case, after relocating DeviceModelInstance from App class to ViewModelBase class, setting it as a public property, then instantiating ViewModelBase instance via XAML:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
         <vm:ViewModelBase/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

And finally referencing this specific ViewModelBase instance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModelBase vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        vm = (ViewModelBase)this.DataContext;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This works for me as intended because only one instance of ViewModelBase (and subsequently only one instance of DeviceModel) gets instantiated via XAML and gets referenced in code-behind.
However, I still don't understand how to do the same the other way around, i.e. instantiating Model objects in code and ONLY referencing them in XAML, not creating their new instances.

Thanks!